# How to increase column width of exported table

Tags: jquery, excel

I am using table to excel and its working fine but i got width issue after exporting into excel. the column contains images and after opening into excel its not obtaining the actual html width.Here is my jquery code. Any help would be appreciated.
        I am using the jquery code from (http://jsfiddle.net/insin/cmewv/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel the images are not within the cells. They hover in a separate layer over the Worksheet. That's why the image width not increases the cell width automatically. So you must specify the cell width in the HTML code.

Example:

```
<table id="testTable">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="150" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
        <col style="width:200px;" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr height="100">
        <td style="text-align:center; border:1px solid;">Text</td>
        <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9a24eed042b7cb501ceb6ea73c09fc46?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="200" height="80"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="100">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid;"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9a24eed042b7cb501ceb6ea73c09fc46?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width="200" height="80"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94tLhmem/1/

Some settings were taken from HTML attributes, other from inline CSS only. Somewhat works in COL elements, others not. Here you have to try what will work better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacinxg=\"0\" width=\"100%\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align=\"center\" style=\"background:#cccccc; font-weight:bold;border-collapse: collapse;font-family: &#39;Open Sans&#39;, sans-serif; padding-top:12px; padding-bottom:12px; padding-left:16px; padding-right:16px; color:#000;\">heading1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><tr>
<td align=\"center\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;font-family: &#39;Open Sans&#39;, sans-serif; padding-top:12px; padding-bottom:12px; padding-left:16px; padding-right:16px; color:#000; border:1px solid #cccccc;\">content1</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```